# Reducing RAM usage with regard to Textures

Tags: opengl

Currently, My app is using a large amount of memory after loading textures (~200Mb)

I am loading the textures into a char buffer, passing it along to OpenGL and then killing the buffer.

It would seem that this memory is used by OpenGL, which is doing its own texture management internally.

What measures could I take to reduce this?

Is it possible to prevent OpenGL from managing textures internally?

Answer (score 2):

One typical solution is to keep track of which textures you are needing at a given position of your camera or time-frame, and only load those when you need (opposed to load every single texture at the loading the app). You will have to have a "manager" which controls the loading-unloading and bounding of the respective texture number (e.g. a container which associates a string, name of the texture, with an integer) assigned by the glBindTexture)

Other option is to reduce the overall quality/size of the textures you are using.

Answer (score 2):

> It would seem that this memory is used by OpenGL,

Yes

> which is doing its own texture management internally.

No, not texture management. It just need to keep the data somewhere. On modern systems the GPU is shared by several processes running simultanously. And not all of the data may fit into fast GPU memory. So the OpenGL implementation must be able to swap data out. The GPU fast memory is not storage, it's just another cache level. Just like the system memory is cache for system storage.

Also GPUs may crash and modern drivers reset them in situ, without the user noticing. For this they need a full copy of the data as well.

> Is it possible to prevent OpenGL from managing textures internally?

No, because this would either be tedious to do, or break things. But what you can do, is loading only the textures you really need for drawing a given scene.

If you look through my writings about OpenGL, you'll notice that for years I tell people not to writing silly things like "initGL" functions. Put everything into your drawing code. You'll go through a drawing scheduling phase anyway (you must sort translucent objects far-to-near, frustum culling, etc.). That gives you the opportunity to check which textures you need, and to load them. You can even go as far and load only lower resolution mipmap levels so that when a scene is initially shown it has low detail, and load the higher resolution mipmaps in the background; this of course requires appropriate setting of minimum and maximum mip levels to be set as either texture or sampler parameter.

Comment: What would be a good way to implement this kind of texture streaming without causing frame rate issues while the files are being loaded? I am currently just loading all my textures at the start of running my app.
Also, I do seem to recall that direct x does not cache textures this way

Comment: @aCuria: Pixel Buffer Objects allow to map texture storage allocated with glTexImage2D(data=0) or glTexStorage into process address space. In the frame preparation phase missing textures would be allocated and mapped, then a texture load job enqueued in a secondary thread's list of tasks. The main display thread can render along with only partially loaded textures (some objects may look dull in the meantime) while high detail textures are loaded. This technique is employed for example by the CryEngine, where the incremental texture load is noticeable right after loading a map.